# Authorize by controller ,action and userRole in configure file ,not set the Authorize attribute on every action method ;.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc

my means how to write one authorization filter like mvc4/mvc4,
like this scenario：
I have many controller and  many actions ,at once I have two roles; some time ,we need add new user role, and need to change those actions to three roles;
If the filter can authorize by the configure ,I only modify the configure file;
otherwise, I need change the Authorize attribute on every actions;
I think it's terrible.
I have read the document about on this article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/index) . But can't find solution. So who can help me to resolve it.
thank !

Comment: In the document you linked to, you will find info on policies. Your Authorize attributes can reference a policy and then in startup.cs, you can assign roles to the policy.

Comment: thank you. I know this, but can't get controller and actions  at the function  HandleRequirementAsync  with param AuthorizationHandlerContext;